# Java: public static newInstance()

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain what this piece of code does. For example, what's the second declaration do? i.e. `public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance()` here:

```
public static class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new AlertDialogFragment();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating a new instance of `AlertDialogFragment`  and returning.

Usually we create instnace like

```
AlertDialogFragment adf = new AlertDialogFragment();
```

in your case

```
 AlertDialogFragment adf = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance();
```

See, no difference.

Comment: what is the benefit of newInstance();

Answer (score 2):

In android when your class extends Fragment it needs to have a no arguments constructor(or have no constructor at all) but if you want to set something to every object of the fragment when you create it you can do follwing:

```
public static class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private int value=0;
    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(int value) {
        AlertDialogFragment instance=new AlertDialogFragment();
        instance.value=value;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now you get the `AlertDialogFragment` object by calling:

```
AlertDialogFragment fragment=AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(10);
```

In your case `newInstance` method is not achieving much.

Answer (score 0):

newInstanse() is a method of  java.lang.Class which will create a new instance of the class type specified. It will simply call the default constructor similar to what we do when we call,

```
 Class instance = new Class();
```

The docs for it says:

The java.lang.Class.newInstance() creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

[Source.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_newinstance.htm)